# Marklogic mlcp import operation with filename-as-collection and javascript transform throws exception

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

After some experimenting with Marklogic 8 and Marklogic Content Pump, I'm running into an issue with importing data into a Marklogic database. I'm trying to run an `mlcp import` operation to load data from a set of csv-files with input settings like this:

```
-input_file_path content/csv/  
-input_file_pattern ".*\.csv"  
-input_file_type delimited_text
```

Furthermore, I'm trying out some additional settings to customize the import to my needs. One setting I experimented with is the `-transform_module` setting to apply a custom javascript-based transform module to do some additional transformation during load like this:

```
-transform_module /transform/customTransform.sjs
```

When I run the mlcp import command with these settings the documents are loaded correctly by mlcp and the transform is executed as expected.

Another setting I tried out is the `-filename_as_collection` setting to assign a collection to each imported document with the name of the file the document originated from. I ran some tests and verified that the collections were assigned correctly with this setting.

So the `-transform_module` and the `-filename_as_collection` settings individually work as expected, but the issue occurs when I try to apply both in one import operation. I get the following error message in the command window:

> 15/03/25 11:01:51 ERROR contentpump.MultithreadedMapper: com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentWithFileNameWritable cannot be cast to   org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentWithFileNameWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
>           at com.marklogic.contentpump.utilities.TransformHelper.getTransformInsertQry(TransformHelper.java:163)
>           at com.marklogic.contentpump.TransformWriter.write(TransformWriter.java:97)
>           at com.marklogic.contentpump.TransformWriter.write(TransformWriter.java:46)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:85)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:106)
>           at com.marklogic.contentpump.DocumentMapper.map(DocumentMapper.java:46)
>           at com.marklogic.contentpump.DocumentMapper.map(DocumentMapper.java:32)
>           at com.marklogic.contentpump.BaseMapper.runThreadSafe(BaseMapper.java:51)
>           at com.marklogic.contentpump.MultithreadedMapper$MapRunner.run(MultithreadedMapper.java:376)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Here's the full command I'm executing:
`mlcp import -input_file_path content/csv/ -input_file_pattern ".*\.csv" -input_file_type delimited_text -delimiter ";" -delimited_root_name rootname -namespace http://marklogic.com/somenamespace -transform_module /transform/customTransform.sjs -filename_as_collection`

I'm running Marklogic 8.0-1.1 developer edition and mlcp 1.3-1, both on a single Windows 8.1 machine.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug. Customers who run into this should [contact Support](http://www.marklogic.com/services/support/).